# Count total on couple of conditions

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
id     col1     col2     col3
1      a        1        k1
2      a        2        k2
3      a        -3       k3
4      b        3        k4
```

Now, I want the total of column 'col2' for all rows where 'col1' is the same as 'col1' in the row where 'id' = 1.

So that would be 1+2-3=0.

How would I express this in SQL?

Comment: I'm confused about the last bit: `where 'col1' is the same as 'col1' in the row where 'id' = 1.` .. can you clarify that?

Comment: He means in row with id 1 the col1 = a. So he wants to sum all a's.

Comment: Say col1 contains fruit, and a = apple and b = banana. Col2 contains the number of fruits. If I got id =1, I want to count the amount of apples, if I got id = 4, I want to count the amount of bananas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(col2) from TABLE
where col1 in (SELECT col1 from TABLE where id = 1)
```

Comment: Ah, the where in command. I didn't know that exists. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

you can fire this query

```
select col1 ,sum(col2) as total from tableName group by col1
```

you will get output as

```
col1    total
a       0
b       4
```

and for particular id

```
SELECT col1, sum( col2 ) AS total
  FROM tableName
  WHERE col1 IN ( SELECT col1
                  FROM tableName WHERE id =1)
```