# Delete columns on couple of conditions

Tags: mysql

In a previous question I asked how I could sum up a total based on some conditions: [Count total on couple of conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9127481/675383)

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
id     col1     col2     col3
1      a        1        k1
2      a        2        k2
3      a        -3       k3
4      b        3        k4
```

Now, when I get id=1, I want to delete all the rows where col1=a. 
When I get id=4, I want to delete all the rows where col1=b.

How would I do this in SQL?

I tried based upon previous answer:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE (col1) IN (SELECT col1 FROM table WHERE id = '1')
```

But that gave me an error: `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'table' for update in FROM clause`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been many times on stackowerflow, you cannot `UPDATE/DELETE` table with data from nested select on the same table. There're two ways to do this:

- Load all data before (for example via php, sql procedure)
- Create temporary table like the one you're using, [clone data](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/157-how-to-clone-a-table-in-mysql/) and use temporary table to select items

Comment: It is (I find it) very hard the right way to search for this, so that's why I asked this question

Comment: @Niek yes I know, I was looking for update with the issues some time ago and find 3-4 questions asking this. Unfortunately mysql doesn't provide a way to do this is "nice way" :(

Answer (score 0):

i have another suggested solution for this. What if you create a `STORED PROCEDURE` for this problem?

like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `DeleteRec`(IN xxx varchar(5))

    BEGIN
        DECLARE oID varchar(5);
        SET oID := (SELECT col1 FROM table WHERE id = '1');
        DELETE FROM table WHERE col1 = oID;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

do this helps you?

Comment: Well, I am indeed working in PHP. This adds a lot of complexity, so I guess it would be easier just SELECTing the col1 first and then delete where they are the same.